# C# Expression body inference?

Tags: c#, methods

Let's say I have a small example class:

```cs
public class Test
{
    public Test() {}
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; } = new List<int>();

    public void AddNumber(int number) => Numbers.Add(number);
    public void RemoveNumber(int number) => Numbers.Remove(number);
}
```

How come the above excerpt does not give any warnings or errors when the `void` return type method named `RemoveNumber` uses the `bool` return type `List<int>.Remove(int item)` method? Should the return types of both the calling method and the called method not match?

Comment: Since the `RemoveNumber` method returns `void`, the compiler simply ignores the return type of `Numbers.Remove` (that it, it compiles it to the method `void RemoveNumber(int number) { Numbers.Remove(number); }` rather than `{ return Numbers.Remove(number); }`. If it didn't, then that would be annoying.

Comment: But doesn't the `=>` syntax imply a return?

Comment: @JansthcirlU Not if the containing method is `void`.

Comment: Note that you see the same thing with other uses of the `=>` syntax: `Action<int> foo = x => Numbers.Remove(x)` is perfectly legal

Comment: FWIW, if you had Code Analysis turned on, you **will** get a warning CA1806 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1806 unless you explicitly discard the return `bool` of `.Remove` like so: `public void RemoveNumber(int number) => _ = Numbers.Remove(number);`

Comment: I see, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The C# documentation's page on Expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) says (emphasis mine):

> An expression-bodied method consists of a single expression that **returns a value whose type matches the method's return type**, or, for methods that return `void`, **that performs some operation**.

So the C# language is making a special-case exception for `void`, so so given a member of this form:

```
T Name() => Expr;
```

...then `typeof(Expr)` must match `T` - excepting when `T` is `void` (as it is in your case) in which case `Expr` is a method *that performs some operation* and `Expr`'s return value is implicitly discarded.

C# does not support *type inference* for scenarios like these (if it did you wouldn't have specified `void` anyway).

---

As for why there's no warning or error - that's because you have Code Analysis turned-off. If you were to enable it in your project then your code would get a `CA1806` warning because the return `bool` from `Numbers.Remove(number)` is being ignored - the fix is to add an explicit discard (`_ =` ), like so:

```
public void RemoveNumber(int number) => _ = Numbers.Remove(number);
```

Comment: This behaviour matches the behaviour inside a method: you can call any method disregarding its return value. This ultimately comes from C where you can do the same, although you can easily enable compiler warnings for it. In the interest of correct programs it would probably be better if this behaviour was disallowed but it would be a breaking change.